# Converting rows to columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in the following structure in pandas dataframe

```
User    day games_won   games_draw  games_lost  tips_taken
user1   1   10               4          2         5
user2   1   16               7          1         3
user1   2   2                8          7         0
```

And I want it to be converted into the following format

```
User    day games_won_day1  games_won_day2  games_draw_day1  games_draw_day2  games_lost_day1   games _lost_day2  tips_taken_day1 tips_taken_day2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by setting the index, then unstacking. Finally, fix the headers.

```
df2 = df.set_index(['User', 'day']).unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('{0[0]}_day{0[1]}'.format)

df2

       games_won_day1  games_won_day2  games_draw_day1  games_draw_day2  games_lost_day1  games_lost_day2  tips_taken_day1  tips_taken_day2
User                                                                                                                                       
user1            10.0             2.0              4.0              8.0              2.0              7.0              5.0              0.0
user2            16.0             NaN              7.0              NaN              1.0              NaN              3.0              NaN
```

If you don't want "User" as the index in the output, you can reset it after. I think it makes sense to keep, however.